# Come October 1st, can I iframe non-SSL sites within my SSL-Enabled FB App?

Tags: facebook, iframe, ssl

Since FB is requiring all iframed apps to be hosted under SSL come October 1st, how will this affect people like me who have apps that iframe content from non-SSL domains?

For example:
My app domain is: https://myfbapp.com/appfolder
In my index.php file in my /appfolder, I have images and iframed sites that aren't SSL. For example, I might have a couple of images embedded on my site that are from tinypic. Since they use a non-SSL format for their pictures, what would happen?

This question applies to all non-SSL content being embedded or iframed on your SSL enabled app domain/folder.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Facebook will just be checking for the ssl cert. However, your browser may complain about the mixture of secure and unsecure items when then they are served in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i hope this link help you

[Facebook Secure Browsing (HTTPS), iFrame Tabs & Mixed Content Warnings](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150223945345844&comments)

*Files that MUST Be HTTPS to Avoid the Mixed Secure and Nonsecure Content Warning:

```
Images — <img /> tag;

External CSS (.css) and JavaScript (.js) files
```

or put the images in same directory appfolder and relative link.